# Add space between text and alert block

Tags: beamer, margins

I'm making a poster with beamer and using alertblocks, but within the alert block, I want there to be more white space between the text on both sides and the margin of the alert block. I basically don't want the text to go right up to the edge of the alert block on the right and left sides.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\begin{alertblock}{Introduction}
Paragraph of random text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{alertblock}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your text in a `parbox` or a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{alertblock}{Introduction}
Paragraph of random text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{alertblock}

\begin{alertblock}{Introduction}
\centering
\parbox{.8\textwidth}{Paragraph of random text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah}
\end{alertblock}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]